# Is the weather in the tutorial area set?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I watched a couple of speedruns of Breath of the Wild, and I'm now wondering...

The tutorial, in a speedrun, features quite a bit of climbing. That would be screwed if, by bad luck, the runner would get rain.

But in 10-15 runs I've seen, I don't think I've seen one abort because of that.

So is the weather in the tutorial area set, so it's always sunny? or do the sample of runs I've seen been lucky?

Comment: I can't confirm whether it is set during the tutorial (before you get the glider), but I have been there after the fact and it has been raining.  It is still possible that the tutorial is a special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching about 8 speedruns, the weather seems to always be sunny. Even the incoming weather is shown a sunny.

So it's fair to assume that in the tutorial, the weather is set to sunny.

Comment: Did you watch them live or after the fact? Cause people might just start over if they hit rain, and not post the video.

Comment: Watched most of them live